# How does light dissipate?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

Wondering how light dissipates in both forward and sideways directions?  I am doing a report on is eflux proportional to $d^{2}$ and am struggling to understand the motion and travel of light and how it decreases in flux as distance increases.

Comment: Flux only decreases like $1/d^2$ if the electric field is spherical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Light doesn't dissipate (see below for important qualifier): instead the 'amount' of light that crosses a given area (the flux) changes.

To see why this is think of a source of light which is (approximately) a point: a light bulb will do.  Out of this source is coming a certain, fixed, total amount of light per second.  In fact the light bulb is spitting out a certain number of photons per second, and that number is constant (approximately: obviously the light can get brighter or dimmer and this corresponds to the rate that it emits photons changing, but we can ignore that).

Once the light has emitted these photons, they are not created or destroyed: the number of them is constant (again, see caveat below).  So the number of photons per second crossing any surface surrounding the light bulb is the same.

So, now, consider two spheres surrounding the bulb, one of which has radius $r_1$, and one of which has radius $r_2$.  The number of photons crossing each of these spheres is the same.  But the surface area of the spheres is not the same: the first sphere has area $4\pi r_1^2$, and the second has area $4\pi r_2^2$.  So the number of photons crossing a given unit area of the spheres is different.  And, in fact, if the total number of photons per second is $N$, then the number per unit area is

$$\frac{N}{4\pi r^2}$$

for a sphere of radius $r$.  This quantity is the flux, and as you can see it goes like $1/r^2$.  The reason it goes like $1/r^2$ is not because light dissipates, but because *area of surfaces goes like $r^2$* in three-dimensional space: the total amount of light (of photons) is constant, but the area goes up like $r^2$.

---

Caveat.  I said above that light / photons are neither created nor destroyed.  Well, of course, this isn't true: photons can collide with atoms and be absorbed or scattered, with different numbers of lower-energy photons being re-emitted, and various other similar processes can happen.  But if there is a vacuum, or a gas which is transparent to light at the frequencies you care about, then to a very good approximation you can assume that they aren't created or destroyed (except by the light itself and by whatever they finally crash into).

Caveat 2: everything above is fairly simple-minded: a real quantum-field-theory person would pick holes in almost all of it.  But it gives a good enough impression of what happens, I think.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks for your help. Helps a lot